# Async methods that do not need cancellation

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

Learning cancellation of async tasks found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx):

> As part of supporting the task-based async programming model in the
>   .NET Framework 4.5, we added the `CancellationToken` structure to the
>   signatures of a large set of async APIs in the .NET Framework. For
>   example, the `HttpClient` class exposes a `GetAsync` method overload that
>   accepts a cancellation token. However, **it is not essential for all
>   async methods to support cancellation**. For instance, if you look at
>   the `HttpContent` class, the `LoadIntoBufferAsync` method does not expose
>   an overload with a cancellation token.

What is fundamental difference between asynchronous operations that expose `CancellationToken` in their signatures and ones that don't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is fundamental difference between asynchronous operations that expose CancellationToken in their signatures and ones that don't?

Asynchronous operations that expose CancellationToken in their signatures:

- Can be cancelled

Asynchronous operations that don't expose CancellationToken in their signatures:

- Can't be cancelled; or
- they're cancellable some other way (e.g. `yourAsyncObject.Dispose` wraps up everything nicely)

Comment: Why they can't be cancelled? What's the reason?

Comment: @UserControl Ignoring the "cancellable some other way" bit, the reason you can't cancel them is ... because you can't cancel them. [`await Task.Delay(9999999999);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [`await Task.Delay(99999999, myCancellationToken)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194865(v=vs.110).aspx). How are you going to cancel the first one if it doesn't take a cancellation token? (And don't say `Thread.Abort`.)

Comment: As for "why don't they support cancellation" it can be a) laziness b) they only call other asynchronous methods that don't support cancellation c) they're implemented synchronously d) they don't have to support cancellation e) all of the above f) other.

Comment: To add to this comment, the "why" it cannot be canceled is because the cancellation token must be checked inside the operation and the operation be canceled at a pre-specified location. So if the operation involves a loop, it should cancel outside the loop and not inside. Which means the method should check the CancellationToken before or after the loop. A CancellationToken simply allows the implementor to exit out of the operation at specific points in the code, while Thread.Abort (the non-TPL way to cancel operations) will cancel wherever the code execution is at the moment.